# How to make existing device IOT only?

Tags: ios, iphone, iot

For iOS application, IOT(Internet of thing) is a new things.and we can connect our device with other hardwares.

My question is , is there any way by which i can connect our existing devices like (Air Conditioner,Other ele. component) IOT only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one of the best example for connecting and controlling such devices like A.C., TV, etc with your iOS device.

It's Open Source so you can explore more.

IRKit:

http://getirkit.com/en/

(opensource infrared remote controller).
IRKit is a WiFi enabled Open Source Infrared Remote Controller device.
Home electronics with an infrared remote, like air conditioners, TVs, lights can be controlled using iPhone and iPad via IRKit.

IRKit works with IRKit's official app and you can easily create iOS apps to send IR signals to control home electronics using IRKit iOS-SDK .

You can create apps for example that does:

```
Use location, turns on air conditioner when you arrive near your home.
Press one button to turn off all your home electronics when you leave home.
Connect with Facebook, and automatically change your TV's channel to which your friend is watching.
```

Hope It will help.

Answer (score 3):

If your component have any types of connectivity which is suitable for iOS devices the you can do this, like:

If your Air Conditioner has bluetooth connectivity and it can handle command like turn on/off or controlling temperature, then you can do it with any kind of device that can communicate with the electrical components.

I used to turn off my computer via internet. There was a process running in my computer that hits an URL, receive JSON data and if it gets shutdown flag yes, it turn itself off. I can set that flag from my mobile. The lacking was I could not turn on.

**Edit:**

Yes you can, but you have to do a lot of hardware related work. like: Bluetooth Relay Controller. [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwLw7Db32TI).

Comment: Thanks @Rashad , If my AC has not this type of connectivity,  can i do it with external hardware ? if yes then do you have any idea of this kind of hardware devices ?